# C Memory leak, concating in a while loop

Tags: c, memory-leaks

My program has a memory leak, but I think I've found the cause of it. What I'm doing is adding all the words from the standard input into one string using a concat function.

Here's one function:

```
Word* readWords(FILE *file) {
    char buffer[201]; 
    char* all_words_string = "";   
    Word* word_node_list = NULL;   

    char* cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
    while (cp != NULL) {   
        all_words_string = concat(all_words_string, cp); 
        cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
    } 
    char** word_list = wordList(all_words_string); //You can probably ignore this
    free(all_words_string);
    word_node_list = count_words(word_list); //Ignore this
    freeWordList(word_list); //Ignore this
    free(word_list); //Ignore this

   return word_node_list;
}
```

Which calls upon the function concat:

```
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2){
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

And I think the while loop

```
    while (cp != NULL) {   
        all_words_string = concat(all_words_string, cp); 
        cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
    }
```

is responsible for my memory leak. Because I allocate all this space in concat, then remove the pointer to it, then I only free the last instance of this.

Is this the cause of my memory leak? If so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You have analyzed the problem correctly.  Every `malloc()` and `calloc()` should be paired with a corresponding `free()`, which you fail to do.  Your code also has a few other infelicities, too, such as failing to check function results for error conditions.

I suggest you look into `realloc()`, which will ease your problem significantly.  In terms of the above prescription, it allows you to avoid interposing extra `malloc()` calls before a `free()`.  Also, its behavior would allow you to avoid some slight weirdness with your initialization of `all_words_string`.  For example:

```
Word *readWords(FILE *file) {
    char *all_words_string = NULL;  /* NULL, not "" */
    char *cp;
    /* ... */

    cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
    while (cp != NULL) {   
        all_words_string = concat(all_words_string, cp); 
        cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
    } 

    /* ... */

    free(all_words_string);

    /* ... */
}

char* concat(char *base, const char *to_add){
    /* when its first argument is NULL, realloc() works like malloc(): */
    char *result = realloc(base, strlen(base) + strlen(to_add) + 1);

    if (result != NULL) { /* realloc() (and malloc()) returns NULL on failure */
        /* no need to copy the original string */
        /* no need to free it, either */
        strcat(result, to_add);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I like the `realloc`, but it has the caveat of not working with string constants (would crash). So you can't do `concat("foo", "bar")`.

Comment: @DarkDust, you are half right -- this version with `realloc()` does not work when the *first* argument is a string constant, nor can it accommodate even a `const` first argument without violating `const`-correctness.  I have just updated it to accommodate a `const` second argument, however, and a string constant for the second argument should be fine.  None of this is a problem for the OP's situation, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the result in a new variable so you can free the old one before assigning the new value. For example:

```
// Need to allocate an empty string dynamically so we can free it
// later on.
char* all_words_string = malloc(1);
all_word_string[0] = 0; 

...

char* tmp = concat(all_words_string, cp);
if (tmp != NULL && tmp != all_words_string) {
    free(all_words_string);
    all_words_string = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I tried that before but got memory clobbered before allocated, but  I changed the initialization of all_words_string to     char* all_words_string = malloc(10);  

and it works, thanks! Question answered

Answer (score 3):

When you're looking for memory leaks, you need to count the number of `malloc`s and `free`s and make sure they match.

You might say you have one `malloc` and one `free` in this code, which is true. But - you call the `malloc` from inside a loop.

So every time you go round this loop:

```
while (cp != NULL) {   
    all_words_string = concat(all_words_string, cp); 
    cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
}
```

you call malloc once. And when you pop out of the loop you have done an unspecified number of mallocs (possibly zero) and no frees.

Then you do this:

free(all_words_string);

So you have now done 1 `free` and 0, 1 or two or more `malloc`s.

The first of those will result in a crash (as you are freeing a string which wasn't `malloc`ed), the 2nd will be fine, and the 3rd will result in memory leaks.

You need to code something more like this:

```
char *all_words_string = strdup("");
...
while (cp != NULL) {   
    char *tmp = concat(all_words_string, cp); 
    free(all_words_string);
    all_words_string = tmp;
    cp = fgets(buffer, 201, file);
} 
...
free(all_words_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are every time causing a leak while entering :

```
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2){
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

Instead of calling malloc here consider calling realloc. 
replace below line

char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);

with

s1 = realloc(s1, (strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1));

This should take care of freeing the previously allocated memory dynamically.